# How does one lift higher-order ODEs (and PDEs) on Manifolds?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, vector-fields

In a course on Manifolds its often emphasized that [integral curves of] vector fields are the right way to do ODE theory without coordinates.  I'd say that ODEs and vector fields are morally the same.  My understanding is that integral sub-manifolds of distributions are essentially first-order PDEs.

But we also like to study ODEs and PDEs of arbitrary order.  Do these have their own place on a manifold?  There's a couple objects one could write down whose coordinate representations will involve higher derivatives, such as $\nabla_v\dot{x}$, or $(\nabla_v)^n\dot{x}$.  Probably if you write down the coordinate equation for an integral curves of a section in $TTTTTT\dots TM$ it will also involve higher derivatives. Nothing stands out as nearly so obvious as in the first-order case.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Jet spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics))?

Comment: Yes, actually.  And they should have occurred to me a lot earlier.

Comment: That concept still feels very much coordinate-based.  One particular coordinate is mandated to act like the derivative of one particular other coordinate... no?

Comment: Yes and no.  The usual formulation is with coordinates, but one can reformulate using covariant derivatives to obtain a coordinate-free version.

Comment: One can (sort of laterally) get to this via Lie symmetries and contact transforms by extending the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) to higher symmetries.

Comment: Sounds familiar.  I might have known better what you're talking about two years ago...

Comment: Vector fields along curves are another one: the ODE for geodesics is second order (although, on the cotangent bundle, it can be reformulated as a first order system...)